# Javascript regex match Twitter username, but exclude colon

Tags: javascript, regex

Using the Twitter API I am trying to link any @ symbols to the persons account eg.
`@stackoverflow` goes to `https://twitter.com/stackoverflow`.

This is working well below except for when I am looking at Retweets which have the syntax

```
RT @stackoverflow:
```

The first regex works well but it keeps the : so I would like to remove the last character if it is a `:`. How can I match the `@stackoverflow` pattern but remove the `:` from it. (I don't want to remove the `:` from the whole string as it may also have links in it)

```js
var str = 'RT @stackoverflow: Great ...'
 str = str.replace(/@(\S*)/g, '<a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/$1">@$1</a>')
 str = str.replace(/:$/,"") //doesn't do anything
 console.log(str) // returns RT <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/stackoverflow:">@stackoverflow:</a> Great ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `/@(\S*)/g` use `/@(\w+)/gi`, because Twitter usernames are exactly confined to what [`\w`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word) represents: `a-z`, and `0-9` and `_`. As stated in this [Twitter support article](https://support.twitter.com/articles/101299#):

> A username can only contain alphanumeric characters (letters A-Z, numbers 0-9) with the exception of underscores, as noted above. Check to make sure your desired username doesn't contain any symbols, dashes, or spaces.

```js
var str = 'RT @stackoverflow: Great ...'

str = str.replace(/@(\w+)/gi, '<a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/$1">@$1</a>')
 
console.log(str)
```

Comment: Maybe `/@(\w+)/gi` to require the character after `@`.

Answer (score 1):

@trincot's answer works well (I gave it a vote), but I am going to add my answer for anyone who encounters this and the `\w` doesn't fit their needs. For those who need to use the `\S` for any reason you can wrap the username in parenthesis to separate it out as a second back reference and then use that in the replace statement. In this case it would be `$2` instead of `$1`.

```js
var str = 'RT @stackoverflow: Great ...'
str = str.replace(/@((\S*):)/g, '<a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/$2">@$1</a>')
str = str.replace(/:$/,"") //doesn't do anything
console.log(str)
```